# Close button on datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I have this in

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
showOn: "button",
buttonImage: "http://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/datepicker/images/calendar.gif",
buttonImageOnly: true,
```

And other codes. I want when I close datepicker, don't show "button" any more.

Comment: @BhavinRana Yes. But it's not interesting. I need only how ShowOn: "button" disable or not showing.

Comment: still confusing :( write more if u can !

Comment: here is my problem: (jsfiddle.net/JBrvn/43) When I more then 1 pick in "from" datepick show me more then one button in "to" datepick. I hope you understand me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `onClose` callback for `datepikcer`.

```
onClose : function()
{
  // code to remove the button
}
```

**onClose**

```
Function( String dateText, Object inst )
```

> Called when the datepicker is closed, whether or not a date is selected. The function receives the selected date as text ("" if none) and the datepicker instance as parameters. this refers to the associated input field.

Comment: And how I remove button? Inside onClose?

Comment: remove `ui-datepicker-trigger` class `DOM` using `$('.ui-datepicker-trigger').remove()`

Comment: here is my problem: (http://jsfiddle.net/JBrvn/43/) WHen I more then 1 pick in "from" datepick show me more then one button in "to" datepick. I hope you understand me.